# Error using Python GetModelResponse

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This code works in cpp.

```
 ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<gazebo_msgs::GetModelState>("/gazebo/get_model_state");
 gazebo_msgs::GetModelState getmodelstate;
 getmodelstate.request.model_name ="rrbot";
 client.call(getmodelstate);
```

But in python ...

```
 # Take pose from gazebo: ignore rviz pose: 
 rospy.wait_for_service("/gazebo/get_model_state")
 client = rospy.ServiceProxy("/gazebo/get_model_state", GetModelState)
 getmodelstate = client(model_name="rrbot")
 
 # Set starting data x,y and theta for odometry used in handelerJointControllerState
 self.theta = getmodelstate.response.pose.orientation.z
```

I get the following error:

```
 self.theta = getmodelstate.response.pose.orientation.z
AttributeError: 'GetModelStateResponse' object has no attribute 'response'
```

Any thoughts on the nature of this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203398/error-using-python-getmodelresponse/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9783/programmatically-get-modelstate-from-gazebo/). Looks like you might need to add a `relative_entity_name` variable in the request and that the response does not have a `response` field, rather you should use `self.theta = getmodelstate.pose.orientation.z`. I have not tried the code from the linked answer, but it looks reasonable and was accepted as a solution for making the exact same service calls you are trying to make.

Also, the `z` field in orientation is part of a quaternion and *not* equal to yaw. See [tf/transformations.py](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython#transformations.py) for how to convert quaternions to Euler angles.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on 2015-02-18**:
much thanks

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2016-12-12**:
Could you explain what relative_entity_name is?

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2016-12-13**:
The [GetModelState](http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/gazebo/html/srv/GetModelState.html) service has a request portion that contains `model_name` and `relative_entity_name`. The service documentation states: `return pose and twist relative to this entity`.

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2016-12-13**:
Thanks, basically thanks to this field you can specify in which frame the pose information should be expressed. You can leave it empty or specify for example "world"